# Xauthority problem xdpyinfo: unable to open display "".

Tags: ssh, x11, sshd, xauth, xhost

I am trying to run a program after enabling X windows port forwarding.

My sshd_config file in /etc/ssh/sshd_config is configured such that:

```
X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
X11UseLocalhost yes
```

and my ssh_config file in /etc/ssh/ssh_config has:

```
Host *
ForwardAgent yes
ForwardX11 yes
```

I try to enable X Windows port forwarding with

```
lemon:~ # ssh -X localhost
lemon:~ # echo $DISPLAY

lemon:~ # /usr/bin/SMclient
xdpyinfo:  unable to open display "".
Unable to launch GUI due to X server display setting problem, Exiting .
```

So $DISPLAY is set to nothing. I have tried everything I've seen online. Originally there was no .Xauthority file so I copied from 
    /var/run/gdm/auth-for--/database
and renamed the file .Xauthority

I then tried

```
lemon:~ # xauth generate :0 . trusted
Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyxauth: (argv):1:  unable to open display ":0".
```

When this didn't work, I deleted the old .Xauthority file and then:

```
lemon:~ # touch ~/.Xauthority
lemon:~ # xauth generate :0 . trusted
No protocol specified
xauth: (argv):1:  unable to open display ":0".
```

And many others suggested to run host + which just leads to

```
lemon:~ # xhost +
xhost:  unable to open display ""
```

Comment: Fiddling with `.Xauthority` and `xhost` is pointless because that's not where you have a problem (but be careful, your fiddling may have caused another problem, depending on what you've ended up with in `.Xauthority`). These are about authorizing the connection to the display, but you don't have a display to connect to. You need to figure out why `DISPLAY` is not set. Do you have anything that changes `DISPLAY` in your startup file (`/etc/profile`, `~/.bashrc`, `~/.profile`, `~/.bash_profile`, …)? If so remove it.

Comment: Can you still run X programs without going through SSH? (Your fiddling may have broken that. If so I suggest you log out and back in.) What does `echo $DISPLAY; ssh -X localhost 'echo $DISPLAY'` show?

Comment: What distro are you using?

Comment: Did you try `export DISPLAY=:0.0" ?

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil', I have a similar question for which I can't find an answer. You seem to know this subject well, is there any chance you wouldn't mind taking a look at it? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/630428/invalid-mit-magic-cookie-1-when-i-run-mpirun
(My apologies for my bad manners in asking this in this way. I don't usually do this but I am a bit desperate.)

Answer (score 0):

Along with all the above on macOS13 Ventura you must:
In System Settings, General, Allow in Background, XQuartz must be turned on.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).