# Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 when I run mpirun

Tags: terminal, xauth

Suddenly whenever I run `mpirun` I get the error `Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 key`. I think this might have started after I killed a command using `mpirun` that had been launched from a python console.

I looked at `$XAUTHORITY` and found no `.Xauthority` file. I also tried `xhost +local:` in the terminal but the problem remains.

I have only used `mpirun` to run things locally on my pc.

(For the most part mpirun does seem to do what it is supposed to, but I believe it also now creates errors in things that were working perfectly before.)

Simply running the below shows the warning for example (nonsense minimal example):

```
/usr/bin/mpirun -n 1 echo "bla"
```

---

I ran

```
export XAUTHORITY="$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR"/Xauthority
```

because it solved the issue for someone else but it seemed to have made things worse (?). Now it says

```
No protocol specified
```

whenever I run mpirun.

By going through the steps in https://superuser.com/a/941244/728074 it goes back to saying `Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 key`.

Also my `$DISPLAY` was set to nothing it seems. I tried setting it to `":1"` or `":0"` but that does not resolve the issue. I also do not know whether it had a value before but some posts suggest its value is relevant for this error.

---

System: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Comment: Are you working on a remote host? If so, how do you connect to that host?

Comment: @Kusalananda, no I am just the only user account (besides root) using my laptop locally. There is no ssh involved and nothing remote.

Comment: Isn't `mpirun` using `ssh` to connect to the local system if you run multiple parallel instances of your program? Is the program you're trying to run in parallel something that is actually using X windows?

Comment: @Kusalananda, it could be. I am actually not sure. It is an application that I did not write where it should be run with mpirun. It coulde be using ssh to connect locally but then I don't know.

Comment: @Kusalananda, do you understand what might be wrong? I would be so grateful.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is related to `libhwloc` library. This library is used by OpenRTE (that is the OpenMPI component to launch parallel processes) to explore the hardware topology of the node. During the `hwloc_topology_load()` call, the `libhwloc` loops over all its components, which are designed as plug-ins. The `gl` component (located in a place like: `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hwloc/hwloc_gl.o`) tries to use `XOpenDisplay()` and other X11 calls, that results in those messages. One can disable this libhwloc component by setting up an environment variable:

`export HWLOC_COMPONENTS="-gl"`

For HPC clusters this component is of no use (typically), so this seems to be a generic solution.

Comment: not solving the issue for debian bookworm 12

Answer (score -1):

my case is a little bit different, but I'm throwing this answer in case it helps anyone.

This solved it for me: https://askubuntu.com/a/1365242/1048079

just

```bsh
sudo apt remove openmpi-bin
sudo apt-get autoremove mpich
```

then

```bsh
sudo apt install mpich
```